# Using system() function in c++ cause command prompt window appear and disappear

Tags: c++, command-prompt

I use system() function to open a pdf in c++. It works correctly but while opening pdf, the command prompt window appear and disappear. I don't want this window to appear. What should I do?

Comment: *Don't* use `system` to execute commands? Windows (which I assume you're using) have other and often better functions to execute external programs, especially opening documents with their correctly associated program. For example, read about [`ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @ joachim I search about the methods and this seems simpler and better one. Which better methods do you suggest?

Comment: @maryamT: `system` indeed is simple (no options), but you don't want simple.

Comment: yes, I used ShellExecute and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a different higher-level API. What that would be depends on what platform you are on, what framework you are using. 
Something like win32's *ShellExecute* or this in MacOSX/Cocoa:

```
NSWorkspace *workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
[workspace openFile:aFilePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using win32, then use

ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(),SW_HIDE);

This will do the trick.